# How to change tabbed page icon color?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, icons, tabbedpage

I am working on the tabbed page in xamarin.forms android, Though I have placed images which are white in color, they are displaying in dark red color.

Here is the Tabbar.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
app:tabGravity="fill"
app:tabMode="fixed"
android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

Do I have to change anything here to get the Icon as I wanted?[image]

Those two images are actually white colored, how can change them to white?

Comment: according to what i see in the XML `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` is set as the background which tells me that is your primary color(red)

Comment: How did you add those images? Can you add more relevant code.

Comment: I added those images to drawable @JackHua-MSFT. Thanks for the response I solved the as the following.

Comment: Thanks for the response @G.hakim, I solved the issue as the following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by adding the following lines in view.

```
  xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#66FFFFFF"
        android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="White"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
<TabbedPage UnselectedTabColor="White" SelectedTabColor="Black"> CONTENT </TabbedPage>
```